# Effect of High Muscle on 'Bands' of Body Fat

Tags: body-fat

When a person is highly muscular, does the accuracy of 'less than 17% Body Fat and you should be relatively healthy' change?

For example, it's possible for a person to be say 6'3 and 70kg or 6'3 and 110kg, and so saying 17% body fat would workout to a noticeably different actual masses of fat in the body. However, does the added muscle mean the fat is more 'spread around', or should men aim to always have no more than say 13.6kg of Fat in their Body (17% of the Average Weight for Men of ~80kg)?

Answer (score 4):

If you have 17% body fat, then you will have the same percentage of fat whether you are 60kg or 100kg. If you are 60kg and 17% bodyfat, then you have 10.2 kg of fat. (In generic terms, actual measurements will be different, as you just can't lump it all into "bodyfat" and call it good). If you are 100kg and 17%, then you will have 17kg of fat.

You also can't really control where it goes. If your bodies preference is to store it on your hips/waist first, then your butt, it will do so regardless of the rest of the body composition. Fat is also stored in a LIFO (Last In First Out) method, so the last place it went on will be the first place it comes off.

Comment: is there any article referencing that claim of LIFO?

Comment: I couldn't find any scholarly articles, but it's what I remember from my ex phys classes in college, and there are tons of articles both "broscience" and more reputable on the web.