# Losing fat on upper pubic area (FUPA)?

Tags: weight-loss, bellyfat, getting-in-shape

I'm 25 years old and 1.73m tall. In my teenage I was really fat (95KG), then at the age of 22 I decided to lose weight. Currently I'm 75KG which means I'm still 5KG fat I would say. My problem is that when I was fat I had a lower belly that grew just below the navel area because of wearing high jeans I would guess. At that time I thought that I will lose this ugly belly if I lose weight. But until now I still have this lower belly and even more I have a circle on my body just on the place of wear I wear jeans. I really have no idea how to lose this. I sketched a picture for the problem.

This is also causing me problems with clothes especially with shirts. Because when I wear shirts I can close all the buttons, except the last three buttons!!!

I hope if you can provide me with exercises or even English keywords terms for this case so I can search also on the web for videos or so.

I'm sorry but I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm not sure if this question is asked before because I don't know the English terms for this case.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best exercise to lose belly fat fast](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast)

Comment: I upvoted this just for the awesome pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't a way to loose fat in a specific area - despite what commercials want to sell you.  Unlike making muscles larger, where you can focus on specific areas, fat is determined by genetics.  The only way to remove fat from the area mentioned would be liposuction.

That is, you can decrease the fat percentage in your body until this goes away.  If you want it gone first and right now, surgery is the only way.

---

**Edit:**
Also, if you have recently lost a lot of weight, you may have extra skin.  This will eventually tighten over time.  However this is another reason people get plastic surgery - because they're impatient.

Comment: Please see JohnP's answer here: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15444/effect-of-high-muscle-on-bands-of-body-fat

Comment: ah so I don't need plastic surgery after all!

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common question, and what you're asking about is spot reduction.  Bottom line is, spot reduction is a myth.

You likely have more KG of fat than you think-5kg equates to .06 percent, which is extremely low-that's venturing on hospitalization if true.

I will echo others here-trim bodies are built in the kitchen just as much as they are in the gym.  Have faith and remained disciplined about your diet and exercise, as long as they are realistic and healthy.  You can lose that fat, but only if you remain diligent.